# Simple Serilog + ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, serilog

This program doesn't post anything to `ElasticSearch` as seen from `Kibana`. Am I missing something?

```
using System;

using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch;


namespace DemoService
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {         
            var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://ipaddress:9200"))
            {
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv6
            });


            Log.Information("The time is {Now}", DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing CreateLogger() is likely what caused these issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work thus.

```
       var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://ipaddress"))
        {                
            AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
            //AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv6,
            FailureCallback = e => Console.WriteLine("Unable to submit event " + e.MessageTemplate),
            EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback,
            FailureSink = new FileSink("./failures.txt", new JsonFormatter(),
            null)
        }
        ).CreateLogger();

        log.Information(new ApplicationException("This is working!").ToString());
```

Comment: Odd, same issue as you accept this solution is not working for me...  was this with asp.net?